# Give an inherited nested class a separate datatype in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, nested-class

I am attempting to imitate the way STL iterators are declared by using inheritance and nested classes.

I have a parent class `Iterable` with nested class `iterator`.

```c++
class Iterable
{
public:
    class iterator
    { };
};
```

I have two classes, `List` and `Vector`, which inherit from `Iterable` in order to gain the nested class `iterator`.

```
class List : public Iterable
{ };

class Vector : public Iterable
{ };
```

This allows declaration of iterators like this.

```
   List::iterator lIte;
   Vector::iterator vIte;
```

However I would like to have compile time errors when attempting to mix iterators from different derived classes. E.g.

```
lIte = vIte; // throw a compile error
```

But, since the `iterator`s come from the same base class, `Iterable`, the statement above will compile just fine.

An example work around would be to define a new nested class `iterator` which will inherit from `Iterable::iterator` in each class that inherits from `Iterable` (`List` and `Vector`). E.g.

```
class List : public Iterable
{
public:
    class iterator : Iterable::iterator // This "specializes" the datatype of iterator
    { };
};

class Vector : public Iterable
{
public:
    class iterator : Iterable::iterator
    { };  
};
```

Doing the above will successfully cause a compile time error when attempting:

```
   List::iterator lIte;
   Vector::iterator vIte;
   lIte = vIte;
```

However this is a sub-optimal work around as:

1. It involves code duplication in every class that inherits from `Iterable`.
2. It requires C++11 in order for the duplicated `iterator` classes to inherit appropriate constructors from `Iterable::iterator`.

**My question is**, how can I make `List::iterator` and `Vector::iterator` different types without duplicating code or using C++11 constructor inheritance?

Comment: Iterator are generally intimate with the container on which they're designed to iterate. The iterator classes *themselves* may have have a common base (or in the case of the std lib, a common base template type), but sooner or later they're going to be specialized to their host.

Comment: @Daniel: Your question is good, but I fear that you are running into a dead end. You want to make things compatible through derivation and at the same time require them to be incompatible. I think you should go back one step and ask yourself why you need the common base class in the first place. What would I do with an `Iterable` in a function like `void f(Iterable &iterable);`? What are the common operations shared conceptually by all derived class? And the biggest question is: why don't you just use the standard container classes?

Comment: STL is brilliant *because* it did away with inheritance.

Comment: @WhozCraig You and ChristianHackl are both correct. gha.st pointed out that problem as well in his solution. If you're interested, you can read my comments on his solution as to why I initially chose this approach. However, it is certainly apparent to me now that I should change it. Also I am doing this simply as a learning exercise. And it was certainly successful as I learned a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a class template to generate different classes from one common - well template:

```
template<typename T>
struct Iterable
{
    class iterator
    { };
};

class List : public Iterable<List>
{ };

class Vector : public Iterable<Vector>
{ };
```

However, while this solves your immediate problem, it does not look like a proper solution.
In fact, it does not really make sense to give `Iterable` an iterator class at all, unless it is a (potentially polymorphic) base class. After all, iterating over a `vector` works differently from iterating over an `list`.

Since you wish to imitate the C++ standard library, you should be aware that `::std::list` and `::std::vector` do not share any public base classes.

Comment: This is a variation of the Curiously recurring template pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: My original use case was actually only for a list and a binary search tree. Since each of those data structures uses some type of node class, I had the `iterator` class manipulate a parent node class that was also defined in `Iterable`. The parent node class defined common methods such as `next()` and `previous()` while the derived node classes from either list or bst defined how they worked. This approach doesn't work for data structures that don't use nodes however such as a vector, so thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: Also I am merely imitating STL as a learning experience. I am not concerned with the formally implementing it. Thanks for mentioning that requirement as well though.